# TypeError: readFImage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'imgc'

Tags: python, machine-learning, typeerror

I have defined a function as follows

```
def readFImage(imgc):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en', 'hi'])
    result = reader.readtext(imgc ,paragraph=True)
    top_left = tuple(result[0][0][0])
    bottom_right = tuple(result[0][0][2])
    text = result[0][1]
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    img = cv2.imread(imgc)
    spacer = 300
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    for detection in result: 
        top_left = tuple(detection[0][0])
        bottom_right = tuple(detection[0][2])
        text = detection[1]
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,top_left,bottom_right,(0,255,0),3)
        spacer+=15
    for i in result:
        print(i[1])
        print(text)
```

and used the above function as shown below:

```
ReadButton = Button(root,text="READ FROM IMAGE", command = readFImage)
ReadButton.grid(row = 5,column = 2)
```

it's giving me error as in title

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\USER\Documents\CC PROHLT\new.pyl 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
TypeError: readFImage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'imgc'
```

for complete code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image
import easyocr
from gtts import gTTS
from IPython.display import Audio
import cv2

root = Tk(  )

def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                           filetypes =(("PNG File", ".png"),("BMP File", ".bmp"),("JPEG File", "*.jpeg")),
                           title = "Choose a file."
                           ) 
    PathTextBox.delete("1.0",END)
    PathTextBox.insert(END,name)


def readFImage(imgc):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en', 'hi'])
    result = reader.readtext(imgc ,paragraph=True)
    top_left = tuple(result[0][0][0])
    bottom_right = tuple(result[0][0][2])
    text = result[0][1]
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    img = cv2.imread(imgc)
    spacer = 300
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    for detection in result: 
        top_left = tuple(detection[0][0])
        bottom_right = tuple(detection[0][2])
        text = detection[1]
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,top_left,bottom_right,(0,255,0),3)
        spacer+=15
    for i in result:
        print(i[1])
        print(text)
    
    

def readAloud(text):
    tts = gTTS(text)
    tts.save('1.wav')
    sound_file = '1.wav'
    Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)


Title = root.title( "Image Reader!")
path = StringVar()



InputLabel = Label(root,text = "INPUT IMAGE:")
InputLabel.grid(row=2,column = 1)

BrowseButton = Button(root,text="Browse", command = OpenFile)
BrowseButton.grid(row=2,column=2)

PathLabel = Label(root,text = "Path:")
PathLabel.grid(row = 3,column=1,sticky=(W))

PathTextBox = Text(root,height = 2)
PathTextBox.grid(row = 4,column = 1,columnspan=2)

ReadButton = Button(root,text="READ FROM IMAGE", command = readFImage)
ReadButton.grid(row = 5,column = 2)

DataLabel = Label(root,text = "DATA IN IMAGE:")
DataLabel.grid(row = 6,column=1,sticky=(W))

ResultTextBox = Text(root,height = 6)
ResultTextBox.grid(row = 7,column = 1,columnspan=2)

SoundButton = Button(root, text ='Read Aloud', command = readAloud).grid(row = 8, column = 2)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please help me with this... this is my first question on stackoverflow and i am new to coding...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a function as a parameter, ie. in this case your passing the function (with a parameter) to the button, you can do it like so:

`ReadButton = Button(root,text="READ FROM IMAGE", command = lambda: readFImage(parameters))`

However, since it looks like you don't know the actual contents of the parameters when this line of code executes. I'd do it like below:

```
def readFImageWrapper():
    # get the paramters to pass to the function here
    readFImage(parameters)
ReadButton = Button(root,text="READ FROM IMAGE", command = readFImageWrapper)
```